# Vb.Net 2010 - SQL Insert Command with autonumeric value

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm looking to add a row with an autonumeric value using SQL.

I'm using Studio VB 2010. I have a very simple table with 2 fields:
ID Autonumeric
Model  Text field.

```
    constr = "INSERT INTO procedures VALUES('" & txtFName.Text & "')"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(constr, cn)

    cn.Open()
    Me.i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

A message says a parameter is missing,
so my question is...
How can I add in the SQL command this automatic value? (ID)

Should I get the last ID number and +1 ??  I think there's gotta be a simple way to do it.

Thank you.

Update #1
I am now trying parameterized queries as suggested...
I found this example,

```
  Dim cmdText As String = "INSERT INTO procedures VALUES (?,?)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(cmdText, con)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    With cmd.Parameters
        .Add("@a1", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 0
        .Add("@a2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFName.Text
    End With
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
```

But still, I'm geting a Syntaxis error. 
Any thoughts?

Thanks to you all.

---

UPDATE #2
This code seems to work if I give the next ID number, but again, how can I do it automatically?

```
Dim cmdText As String = "INSERT INTO procedures VALUES (?,?)"
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(cmdText, con)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    With cmd.Parameters
        .AddWithValue("@a1", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 3
        .AddWithValue("@a2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFName.Text
    End With
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
```

Any comments?  Thanks again.

UPDATE #3  This Code gives me Syntaxis Error
I just put my only one column to update, the second one is the autonumber column, as I was told to try.

```
 Dim Con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(dbProvider & dbSource)
 Dim SQL_command As String = "INSERT INTO procedures (procedure) VALUES ('Model')"
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(SQL_command, Con)

    Try
        Con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        Con.Close()
        Con.Dispose()
    End Try
```

UPDATE #4 - SOLUTION

I'm putting this code in here in case someone finds it useful.

```
    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Persist Security Info=False;"
    dbSource = "Data Source = c:\gastrica\dabase.accdb"
    Con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource


Dim Con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(dbProvider & dbSource)
    Dim SQL_command As String = "INSERT INTO [procedures] ([procedure]) VALUES (?)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(SQL_command, Con)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    With cmd.Parameters
        .AddWithValue("@procedure", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFName.Text
    End With

    Try
        Con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim varProcedure As String = cmd.Parameters("@procedure").Value.ToString()
        MessageBox.Show("Record inserted successfully. Procedure = " & varProcedure)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        Con.Close()
    End Try
```

Thanks all for your comments and help.

Comment: If you don't specify the columns you want to insert to then you have to provide values for EVERY column in the correct order. If you're not going to do that then you must specify the columns you're inserting to. To be clear, you don't provide the value. The whole point of an AUTOnumber is that it is generated automatically.  You need to change your SQL code to specify the column(s) that you ARE providing values for.

Comment: Also, don't use string concatenation to insert values into the SQL code.  Learn how to use parameters in your ADO.NET code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jmcilhinney.  It works good if I provide both values, but, still I need to insert this autonumeric value automatically.  When I try to specify just the text Column (i.e. Model) a Syntaxis error shows.

Comment: I already told you what to do. Specify the column(s) you want to insert to and provide value(s) for the column(s) you specify.  If you only want to insert to one column then specify that one column and provide that one value.

Comment: Hey @jmcilhinney, it gives me an Syntaxis error.

Comment: Then you did it wrong. If you don't show us what you did, we can't tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  you can check it out in my Update #3. This gives me a Syntaxis error.

Comment: Guess what @jmcilhinney , it worked adding [   ]  ... Dim SQL_command As String = "INSERT INTO [procedures] ([procedure]) VALUES ('Model')"

Comment: You can put brackets around everything if you want but their specific purpose is to force some text to be interpreted as an identifier.  They are only required when that text could be interpreted as something else.  In your case, `procedures` can't be interpreted as anything else so putting it in brackets doesn't hurt but doesn't help either.  On the other hand, `procedure` is a SQL reserved word and will be interpreted as such if you don't wrap it in brackets. I could have told you that in the first place if I'd seen your code, which is why you need to ALWAYS post the relevant code.

Comment: OK. That's good to know.  I'll do it the next time.   Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the columns:

```
INSERT INTO procedures (columnname, columnname2) VALUES ('test', 'test');
```

Here is a sql fiddle showing an example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3cf706/1

Comment: Thanks for you help @sqlsquirrel.

Comment: Answers should always correct the OP to use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
constr = "INSERT INTO procedures (ID, Model) VALUES (0,'" & txtFName.Text & "')"
'or (not sure)
constr = "INSERT INTO procedures (Model) VALUES ('" & txtFName.Text & "')"
```

When use 0 as value, in autonumeric fields SQL insert the next number

Comment: Thanks for you help Eduardo. I have tried both lines, and all I get is a Syntaxis error.  I guess it comes with the parentesis after the table name.

Comment: Answers should always correct the OP to use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

I couldn´t do it, it gives me errors. So I end up with a single variable reaching the next Auto Value. Using a simple SQL command. 
And then, everything runs good.

```
 vNextAuto = GetDB_IntValue("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM procedures ORDER BY ID DESC", "ID") + 1

    Dim SQL_command As String = "INSERT INTO procedures VALUES (?,?)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(SQL_command, Con)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    With cmd.Parameters
        .AddWithValue("@id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = vNextAuto
        .AddWithValue("@a2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFName.Text
    End With

    Try
        Con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'Dim id As String = cmd.Parameters("@id").Value.ToString()
        'MessageBox.Show("Record inserted successfully. ID = " & id)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        Con.Close()
        Con.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Comment: I don't see how this can possibly work for an IDENTITY field, assuming you're using SQL Server. You cannot insert into an IDENTITY field without additional T-SQL. Are you using SQL Server? Is the ID field in fact an IDENTITY field, which is what automatically assigns the ID value? Also note that your method here is ripe for duplicate IDs in a high volume system, which will start throwing errors to the users.

Comment: No, I'm not using SQL Server, I guess I'm using ADO.net (sorry, I'm not an expert in this)  . I'm using this to open up the database dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Persist Security Info=False;"
        dbSource = "Data Source = c:\gastrica\database.accdb"